# mv * folder (avoiding 'cannot move' error)

Tags: zsh, rename

Anytime I want to move thousands of files to a new folder, I always encounter the same problem.

```
> mkdir my_folder
> mv * my_folder
mv: cannot move 'my_folder to a subdirectory of itself 'my_folder'
```

While I think that the error above is harmless (**is it?**) I am wondering if there is a way of avoiding it.

In case it matters, I am interested in a solution in zsh or one that works well across various shells.

Comment: There was a similar question on the Ubuntu SE (although for bash). Perhaps this works for zsh too? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91740/how-to-move-all-files-in-current-folder-to-subfolder

Comment: Use `find -type f -exec mv {} folder \;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In zsh, with the `extended_glob` option enabled, you can use `~` to exclude patterns from globs, so you could use:

```
setopt extended_glob
mv -- *~my_folder my_folder
```

Or use the negation operator (still with `extended_glob`):

```
mv -- ^my_folder my_folder
```

Use braces to avoid typing the directory name twice:

```
mv -- {^,}my_folder
```

In bash (for other answer-seekers using it), you can use Ksh-style extended globs:

```
# If it's not already enabled
shopt -s extglob
mv -- !(my_folder) my_folder
```

You can also use that syntax in `zsh` if you enable the `ksh_glob` option.

Answer (score 5):

If there are only regular files apart from the new subdirectory, you could use find:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} my_folder \;
```

The `-type f` option will only find files (not dirs). `-maxdepth 1` will keep find looking only in `.` (not recurs down into other dirs). The `-exec …` does your move.

In zsh, you can abbreviate this to

```
mv *(.) my_folder
```

Yes, the error is harmless.

Comment: Is there anyway you could mention how `(.)` works in zsh?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Those are glob qualifiers. `*(.)` represents ALL plain files. see the 'Glob Qualifiers' section in the zshexpn man page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
mv * my_folder 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This doesn't actually prevent the error from occuring. It simply hides it by piping it to /dev/null instead of to your terminal window.

Comment: @howardh: Although I would not use the above solution in this particular case, in general, if you deem an error harmless, that's a good way disposing of the error message.

Comment: Poster just wants to hide error, So it's good solution.