# How can i move all files and dir within a dir to its sub dir

Tags: linux, shell, mv

[image]

Here is the directory listing, Parent dir is B, i want to move/copy C, D and filetest.txt to dir E.

How can i do that with a single command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63266/mv-folder-avoiding-cannot-move-error (please excuse my previous flag, I had the wrong question linked).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in directory B:

```
mv C/ D/ filetest.txt E/
```

`mv` can take multiple files/directories as arguments and move them to the last argument.

Comment: yeah okay actually i should i have specified, i had question what if B had hundreds of dir and sub directories to be moved to a sub dir, then how can i do that?

Comment: You should probably read up on wildcards/globs. I suggest this: http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Comment: @AmanArora, your question explicitly says: `(I) want to move/copy C, D and filetest.txt to dir E`, which this Answer does.

Answer (score 0):

In that configuration : you are in B directory, you can simply launch the following command:

```
mv * E/
```

The command will complete with a warning that you can't move E/ to itself.

---

Edit:

> The command
>
> `mv !(E/) E/`
>
> should do the trick. If it doesn't work, run `shopt -s extglob` first.
>
> To also move hidden files/directories (that beginning with a dot), run
>   also `shopt -s dotglob` first. So, to sum up:
>
> `shopt -s extglob dotglob`
>
> `mv !(E/) E/`
>
> `shopt -u dotglob`
>
> (it is always better to unset dotglob to avoid bad surprises).

Explained in that [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91740/how-to-move-all-files-in-current-folder-to-subfolder).

Comment: What's wrong about this answer ?

Comment: terminating in an error isn't my idea of "solved".  there are much more graceful ways of handling this (as linked in the above duplicate question) that your answer is lacking.

Comment: Alright, I have to admit.

Comment: just noticed this edit; you could make it more pertinent to the OP by using their actual file/directory names ("E" instead of "new")